# Help: Random Forest optimization (image classification)

Tags: random-forest, image-processing, parameterization, optimization

I'm having trouble classifying images using a random forest.

The images all have a very similar scale, but they may be rotated arbitrarily around a fixed point in the image.

The core problem is that the images of the test set vary somewhat from the training images. But in this case, it is crucial to train based on the given training set and to test it on the given test set(!).

It's thus easily concluded that, I "simply" need a very robust random forest.

The classes are:

- class 0: images that show an certain plane part (the inside of the engine)
- class 1: images that don't show that part

My learners (node functions) are simple intensity comparisons, that check if a pixel value is lower than another pixel value in the same image:

- I(u1,v1) < I(u2,v2)  -> true/false

My current configuration is:

- supervised learning, all class lables available
- number of positive samples: 100 000
- number of negative samples: 100 000
- image size: 160x120
- tree depth = 6
- number of trees: 400

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Perhaps try a covnet instead of a random forest: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py

Comment: Since the RF is working good but not good enough, I think some tuning should do it. If possible I'd prefer not switching the classifier!

Comment: Try more trees (e.g. 4,000), deeper tress, and tuning the `mtry` parameter (or number of variables considered per split).  Test all these parameters out of sample.

Comment: What means "Test all these parameters out of sample"?

Comment: Fit your model on a training set, and then calculate error on a test set that the model did not see during training: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_set

Comment: OK, sure, just didn't know that expression.

Comment: I tested different depths, but this did not improve the performance.

Comment: I'll now test different boosting / bagging methods, since the combination of the trees semms not to improve the performance so much

Comment: @also try different numbers of candidate features at each split.

Comment: As you have mentioned that images can be arbitrary rotated, so you might consider performing similarity transform based on some feature detector and a reference images, before training or testing the data.